# Python - How to return the data from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm currently working on a GUI where the user inputs data and clicks on a button to run a function that draws a canvas.

The function that draws the canvas takes about 1 minute to run and during those seconds the GUI freezes.

Thus during these seconds I would like to show a page which asks the user to wait (with a little animated gif for example).

Here is the code I'm using (I have replaced the code that plot the Graph by a simple case with time.sleep) :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

TITTLE_FONT = ("Verdana", 30)
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 16)
NORM_FONT = ("Helvetica", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Helvetica", 8)
style.use("ggplot")


class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shared_data = {
            "x1": tk.StringVar(),
            "x2": tk.StringVar(),
            "x3": tk.StringVar()}


        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Titre")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Menu
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.destroy)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageGraph, WaitingPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):

        return self.frames[page_class]


class WaitingPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Calculs en cours", font=TITTLE_FONT)
        label1.pack()
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Veuillez Patienter", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.pack()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller=controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page d'acceuil", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #---------- Boutton pour switcher sur la "Page du graph"

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page du Graph",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageGraph))
        button.pack()

        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="X1", font=NORM_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["x1"])
        self.entry1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="X2", font=NORM_FONT)
        label2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["x2"])
        self.entry2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        label3 = ttk.Label(self, text="X3", font=NORM_FONT)
        label3.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["x3"])
        self.entry3.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Valider", command=self.do_button)
        button2.pack()




    def do_button(self):

        page = self.controller.get_page(PageGraph)
        page.Graph()        




class PageGraph(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        # ---------- Création du canvas vide

        self.f = Figure()
        self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)



    def Graph(self):


        self.controller.show_frame(WaitingPage)

        def real_Graph() :

            time.sleep(5)

            x1 = float(self.controller.shared_data["x1"].get())
            x2 = float(self.controller.shared_data["x2"].get())
            x3 = float(self.controller.shared_data["x3"].get())

            xAxis = [float(x1),float(x2),float(x3)]
            yAxis = [float(x1),float(x2),float(x3)]

            return (xAxis , yAxis)


        threadGraph = threading.Thread(target=real_Graph)
        threadGraph.start()

        #############################################
        ######### Retrieve xAxis and yAxis ?#########
        #############################################

        self.toolbar.update()
        self.a.clear() 
        self.a.bar(xAxis,yAxis)
        self.canvas.draw()

        self.controller.show_frame(PageGraph)




app = GUI()
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.mainloop()
```

In the Graph function : The idea is to run the long calculation in another thread and then to retrieve the data to plot the graph.

Hence my question is : How to retrieve what is returned (here xAxis and yAxis) by a function run in another thread ? (here the function real_Graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot update the graph in other thread, you can use `tkinter.after(...)` to periodically check whether the graph is to be updated in the main thread:

```
def check_progress(self):
    if self.done:
        # calculation done, update graph
        self.a.clear() 
        self.a.bar(self.xAxis, self.yAxis)
        self.canvas.draw()
        # show the graph
        self.tkraise()
    else:
        # calculation not done, schedule next check
        self.after(500, self.check_progress)

def real_Graph(self):
    self.done = False # set calculation not done
    time.sleep(5)
    x1 = float(self.controller.shared_data["x1"].get())
    x2 = float(self.controller.shared_data["x2"].get())
    x3 = float(self.controller.shared_data["x3"].get())
    self.xAxis = [float(x1),float(x2),float(x3)]
    self.yAxis = [float(x1),float(x2),float(x3)]
    self.done = True # set calculation done

def Graph(self):
    self.controller.show_frame(WaitingPage)
    # create other thread to do calculation
    threadGraph = threading.Thread(target=self.real_Graph)
    threadGraph.start()
    # start the progress check
    self.check_progress()
```

Comment: Oh nice ! Thank you very much for that solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. You need to change this part:

```
threadGraph = threading.Thread(target=real_Graph)
threadGraph.start()
```

**TO**

```
Threads = []
threadGraph = threading.Thread(target=real_Graph)
Threads.append(threadGraph)
threadGraph.start()
for t in Threads:
    print(t.join())
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about Threads ! I tried your code but my app crashes when I input the data (x1,x2,x3). I think that I have a deeper problem or a misunderstanding  with tkinter/threads.